# Create a data frame in R from a string that follows a specific keyword

Tags: r, string, split

I have a string as such:

```
"05/05/2005 ANNIVERSARY $367.62 ANNUAL DIVIDEND DECLARED UNDER THE PAIO UP ADDITIONS 20,965 2,203 23,168 | PAID UP ADDITION OPTION. $367.62 PURCHASED PAID UP ADDITIONS OF 2,203 02/15/2006 WITHDRAWAL ($77.50) VALUE OF PAID UP ADDITIONS OF 464 PAID UP ADDITIONS 23,168 (464) 22,704 APPLIED TOWARDS CHECK-O-MATIC PREMIUM DUE 03/05/2006 04/11/2006 05/05/2006 ANNIVERSARY $415.70"
```

I would like to create a data frame in R to extract the date and dollar amounts after the word ANNIVERSARY for the entire string.
Date         Dividend
05/05/2005     $367.62
05/05/2006     $415.70

Thank you in advance.

I tried splitting the string with str_split but don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we just want to extract the dollar amounts and date, we may use `str_extract` with a regex lookaround (or in the new version with capture group)

```
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
dates <- str_extract_all(str1, "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}(?=\\s+ANNIVERSARY)")[[1]]
amounts <- str_extract_all(str1, "(?<=ANNIVERSARY )\\$[0-9.]+")[[1]]
tibble(dates, amounts)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  dates      amounts
  <chr>      <chr>  
1 05/05/2005 $367.62
2 05/05/2006 $415.70
```

---

Or another option is to extract the substring containing 'ANNIVERSARY', read with `read.table/fread`

```
library(data.table)
fread(text = str_extract_all(str1, "\\S+\\s+ANNIVERSARY\\s+\\S+")[[1]], 
   header = FALSE, col.names = c("dates", "amounts"), drop = 2)
       dates amounts
1: 05/05/2005 $367.62
2: 05/05/2006 $415.70
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "05/05/2005 ANNIVERSARY $367.62 ANNUAL DIVIDEND DECLARED UNDER THE PAIO UP ADDITIONS 20,965 2,203 23,168 | PAID UP ADDITION OPTION. $367.62 PURCHASED PAID UP ADDITIONS OF 2,203 02/15/2006 WITHDRAWAL ($77.50) VALUE OF PAID UP ADDITIONS OF 464 PAID UP ADDITIONS 23,168 (464) 22,704 APPLIED TOWARDS CHECK-O-MATIC PREMIUM DUE 03/05/2006 04/11/2006 05/05/2006 ANNIVERSARY $415.70"
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun!!! This works perfectly.  I was struggling with the [[1]] and kept getting dimension errors.